API Gateway and mapping template with path and body parameters
There are lots of questions about the mapping templates but I couldn't find resolution to my problem.
I have a api endpoint path PUT /foo/bar/{clientNumber} and the body is
{
    "progress": {
        "client": {
            "name": "client",
            "site": {
                "name": "site"
            }
        }
    }
}

I have tried to many different solutions to this but somehow I don't seem to get it right. I need my endpoint lambda to get the clientNumber from the path and the progress object from the body.
At the moment I have template like this:
"clientNumber": $input.params('clientNumber'),
"progress" : $util.parseJson($input.body)

And the result is:
Endpoint request body after transformations: 
{
    "clientNumber": "",
    "progress": "{progress={client={name=client, site={name=site}}}}"
}

I'm using CDK to build this, if that's something to consider.
Edit:
With CDK I create LambdaIntegration with LambdaIntegrationOptions' requestTemplate as
{"application/json": JSON.stringify(requestTemplates)}
Where requestTemplates has clientNumber and progress as defined above
Edit 2, as requested:
Creating integration and the method:
const apiResource = api.root.addResource('progress');
const withClientNumber = apiResource.addResource('{clientNumber}');

const integrationForSaveProgress = new LambdaIntegration(
  saveProgressFunction,
  apiUtils.createLambdaIntegrationOptions(["clientNumber"], integrationResponses, 'progress')
);

const putMethod: Method = withClientNumber.addMethod(
  "PUT",
  integrationForSaveProgress,
  {
    ...apiUtils.createMethodOptions(
      [...defaultResponses, ...errorResponses],
      ["method.request.path.clientNumber"]
    ),
    requestModels: {
      'application/json': modelStore.getModel("ProgressModelRequest")
    },
    requestValidator: progressValidator
  }
);

The apiUtils functions:
export function createLambdaIntegrationOptions(
    pathParams: string[],
    integrationResponses: IntegrationResponse[], 
    bodyParam?: string): LambdaIntegrationOptions {
  const requestParams: {[key: string]: string} = {};

  const requestTemplates:any = {};

  // TODO: What should this be?
  pathParams.forEach((item: string) => {
    requestParams[`integration.request.path.${item}`] = `method.request.path.${item}`;
    requestTemplates[item] = `"$input.params('${item}')"`;
  });

  if ( bodyParam ) {
    // TODO What shoud this be?
    requestTemplates[bodyParam] = `$input.json('progress')`;
  }

  const opts = {
    proxy: false,
    requestParameters: requestParams,
    requestTemplates: {"application/json": JSON.stringify(requestTemplates)},
    integrationResponses: integrationResponses
  };

  return opts;
}
export function createMethodOptions(
  methodResponses: MethodResponse[],
  requestParameters: string[] | undefined = undefined,
): MethodOptions {
  const requestParams: {[key: string]: boolean} = {};
  requestParameters?.forEach((item: string) => {
    requestParams[item] = true;
  });
  const opts = {
    apiKeyRequired: true,
    requestParameters: requestParams,
    methodResponses: methodResponses,
  };
  return opts;
}


I believe $input.params('clientNumber') should be $request.path.clientNumber. You need to add your CDK code for the route and integration to the question, though.

The indirection with apiUtils makes it less clear, but I think the setup is correct - try using request.path.clientNumber.  You might need to map the field from the method request to the integration request, I'm not sure.

I'll have to try the request.path.clientNumber. How about progress, that isn't json that I have after transformation

Try $input.json('progress')

I tried that, didn't work :(
"Could not parse request body into json"
